# XSD for having 2 root elements (1 at a time)

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, jaxb2

So here is a complex/retarded situation. I am writing an XSD and there happens to be a requirement where i need 2 root elements (1 at any given time)

```
<xs:element name="booksList">
    <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="book" type="bookType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         </xs:sequence> 
    </xs:complexType>   
</xs:element>
```

and then

```
<xs:element name="book" type="bookType"></xs:element>
```

at any given time, either of these element will be used as the root element, so an XML would look like

```
<bookList>
<book>
<author>XYZ</author>
</book>
</bookList>
```

or

```
<book>
<author>XYZ</author>
</book>
```

Both of these XML will be sent back to the user from 2 different URL's i.e. the list will be sent from **localhost/books.xml?author=XYZ** and single book will be sent from **localhost/book_name.xml**

How can i achieve this with one xml ? I tried putting the book definition in the XSD but JAXB2.1 didn't generate any Book class. Is there something which i am missing ?

---

**EDIT1**: BookType has been generated but BookType doesn't have any root element.

Comment: It probably generated a `BookType` class and annotated the fields with `@XMLElement` where necessary. Please list the classes that were generated. Do you have a `BookType` class? Does it have an `@XMLRootElement` annotation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [xml schema and using a choice as the document root](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639259/xml-schema-and-using-a-choice-as-the-document-root)

Comment: Question updated with **BookType** response.

Comment: @EmAe the `BookType` class is the Java representation of `Book`. Annotate it with `@XmlRootElement` and it should work just fine. You can also tweak the element names using `@XmlElement(name="foo")` if necessary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**XML SCHEMA**

> I am writing an XSD and there happens to be a requirement where i need
>   2 root elements (1 at any given time)

The XML schema below supports having the two root elements `booksList` and `book` that you are looking for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="booksList">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="book" type="bookType" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="book" type="bookType"></xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="bookType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

---

**GENERATED MODEL**

> I tried putting the book definition in the XSD but JAXB2.1 didn't
>   generate any Book class.

Your JAXB (JSR-222) implementation will generate a class for the named complex type `bookType`, then for the `bookElement` it will create an `@XmlElementDecl` annotation on the `ObjectFactory` class.

***BooksList***

A class with an `@XmlRootElement` was generated on this class because it corresponds to a global element with an anonymous complex type.

```
package forum11620825;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {"book"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "booksList")
public class BooksList {

    protected List<BookType> book;

    public List<BookType> getBook() {
        if (book == null) {
            book = new ArrayList<BookType>();
        }
        return this.book;
    }

}
```

***BookType***

This class was generated to correspond to the named complex types.

```
package forum11620825;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "bookType", propOrder = {"author"})
public class BookType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String author;

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String value) {
        this.author = value;
    }

}
```

***ObjectFactory***

Global elements that correspond to named complex types have `@XmlElementDecl` annotations generated on the `ObjectFactory` class.  This is necessary since multiple global elements could correspond to named complex types.

```
package forum11620825;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _Book_QNAME = new QName("", "book");

    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    public BooksList createBooksList() {
        return new BooksList();
    }

    public BookType createBookType() {
        return new BookType();
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "", name = "book")
    public JAXBElement<BookType> createBook(BookType value) {
        return new JAXBElement<BookType>(_Book_QNAME, BookType.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

---

**XML**

Below are the XML documents from your question.

***booksList.xml***

```
<booksList>
    <book>
        <author>XYZ</author>
    </book>
</booksList>
```

***book.xml***

```
<book>
    <author>XYZ</author>
</book>
```

---

**DEMO CODE**

When you unmarshal a document in which the root element corresponds to an `@XmlRootElement` annotation you get an instance of the corresponding domain object.  If you unmarshal a document in which the root element corresponds to an `@XmlElementDecl` annotation you get back an instance of `JAXBElement` that wraps a domain object corresponding to the named complex type.

```
package forum11620825;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("forum11620825");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        File input1 = new File("src/forum11620825/booksList.xml");
        BooksList bookList = (BooksList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(input1);

        File input2 = new File("src/forum11620825/book.xml");
        JAXBElement<BookType> je = (JAXBElement<BookType>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(input2);
        BookType bookType = je.getValue();
    }

}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Below is a code fragment demonstrating how to wrap an instance of `BookType` in a `JAXBElement` so that it can be marshalled.

```
ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
JAXBElement<BookType> jaxbElement = objectFactory.createBook(aBookType);
marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, System.out);
```

Comment: How to connvert from Object to XML with this example ? I see that bookType has `XmlElementDecl`. But when i tried to create an object from `BookType` and marshal it to XML, i got an exception `com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "jaxb.test.BookType" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation`

Comment: @EmAe - I have added an update to my answer to demonstrate how to marshal an instance of `BookType`.

Comment: is it possible to have a single XSD with 2 RootElements having same RootElementName "response" but 2 different complexType in it ?

Answer (score 4):

See this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1639259/577228). You can perform the equivalent of an <xs:choice/> on the root element by simply listing the possibilities in order, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="bookList">
        <xs:complexType>
             <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element name="book" type="bookType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
             </xs:sequence> 
        </xs:complexType>   
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="book" type="bookType"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what he posted in the question (just without the `schema` element)?

Comment: I have two `xs:element`s directly under the root.

Comment: In other words, any valid XML document can have only a single root element. If you define multiple root elements in an XML schema, that means that any of those elements can be the root element, but only one in a single XML document (ie., you choose one of the root elements from schema to be the root of the document)