# Unable to understand JAXB Unmarshalling behaviour

Tags: java, xml, jaxb2

Reference to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620825/xsd-for-having-2-root-elements-1-at-a-time). I have following code which is reading XML from the file.

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, "testSchemaChange");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.store.web.ws.v1.model");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
JAXBElement<BookType> jeBookType = (JAXBElement<BookType>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File (BOOK_XML));

BookType bookType = jeBookType.getValue();
logger.log(Level.INFO, "Book recieved: " + bookType.getISBN());
```

I am seeding an XML with `Book` as my root element instead of `BookList`. This example is working fine as long as i keep the full path of the package in the `JAXBContext.newInstance`.

No sooner, did i change

`JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.store.web.ws.v1.model");`

to

`JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(BookType.class);`

I started getting exception `SEVERE: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"book"). Expected elements are (none)`

Can someone explain why is this behaviour ?

P.S:
For sake of convenience my test class and JAXB generated classes are in same package i.e. `com.store.web.ws.v1.model`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is because the `JAXBContext` isn't aware of your `ObjectFactory` class that contains the `@XmlElementDecl` annotation for the `book` element.

When you create a `JAXBContext` on a package name, the it will automatically pull in the `ObjectFactory` class.  If you create a `JAXContext` on classes you need to explicitly include the class with the `@XmlRegistry` annotation (`ObjectFactory` in this case).