# JAXB Generated classes giving namespace cannot be resolved error

Tags: java, namespaces, xsd, jaxb, jaxb2

Reference to my previous 2 posts ([post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620825/xsd-for-having-2-root-elements-1-at-a-time/11623044#11623044), [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658181/unable-to-understand-jaxb-unmarshalling-behaviour)). Now i am stuck at another weird problem (I am noob at JAXB). I have generated the Java classes using my book.xsd (which included bookList and book as root element). Everything is working fine. Now I am creating totally separate XSD for **reviews**.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="reviews">
    <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="review" type="reviewType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         </xs:sequence>
         <xs:attribute name="self" type="xs:anyURI" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="reviewType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="comments" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="rating" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
     <xs:attribute name="self" type="xs:anyURI" />
</xs:complexType>
```

Now when i generate java classes using JAXB, it starts giving me following error like `The element declaration with name 'reviews' and namespace '' cannot be resolved`.

Any idea ?

**UPDATED**
I figured out that i am using a common.xsd which has basic information being used across multiple xsd. Informations like `authorType` etc. Now common.xsd is being used by my books.xsd and reviews.xsd as well and probably thats the reason i am getting this namespace error. How can i avoid this error here?

Schema is already here.

Comment: Can you post the complete xsd by any chance ? It's likely your xml namespace definitions are mixed up.

Comment: This is the complete XSD for reviews, for other xmls, they are in the links (post 1, and post 2).

Comment: I meant the root element, e.g. <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ...

Comment: schema information was already there. stackoverflow didn't render it. i just realized that there is a comment on existing xml that adding schema would add additional baggage for JSON.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to put your schema's elements into a namespace, since it seems JAXB can't resolve 'reviews' (which is in the global namespace ''. Where the two tics represent '' an empty namespace). You do this by modifying the header of your schema like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://your/namespace/goes/here"
 xmlns="http://your/projects/namespace/goes/here"
 xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
 elementFormDefault='qualified'>
```

Line 2 defines your namespace as the target namespace of the schema.
Line 3 puts your namespace into the .xsd files global namespace (so you don't have to prefix your elements, like you prefix the schema's elements with xs:). You can of course alter that line to your own prefix if you want to use it throughout the schema:

```
 xmlns:mylib="http://your/namespace/goes/here"
```

Also since your elements are now in a namespace, you'll have to tell the XML file in which namespace to look for the elements (you can have multiple namespaces at the same time):

```
 <reviews xmlns="http://your/namespace/goes/here">
 ....
 </reviews>
```

For a more in-depth discussion of Schema namespaces i'd recommend the book: XML Schema, author: Eric van der Vlist, O'REILLY