# Error unmarshalling jaxb objects

Tags: java, jaxb2, unmarshalling

I have jaxb objects against an XML schema. That xml schema can have different root element. Which is working perfectly fine in the main project. Based on those generated objects, I am trying to write some test cases.

I wrote following code to get JAXBContext

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.store.web.ws.v1.model");
```

and i get following exception

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.lang.StackTraceElement
        at public java.lang.StackTraceElement[] java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()
        at java.lang.Throwable
        at java.lang.Error
        at public java.lang.Error com.store.web.ws.v1.model.ObjectFactory.createError()
        at com.store.web.ws.v1.model.ObjectFactory

    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:106)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:466)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1157)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:128)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:277)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:372)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:337)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:244)
    at com.store.web.ws.v1.resource.RequestInfo.main(RequestInfo.java:171)
```

However, the moment i change my context line to

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(BookType.class);
```

I get following exception `SEVERE: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"book"). Expected elements are (none)` which is understandable based on my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658181/unable-to-understand-jaxb-unmarshalling-behaviour)

Can someone help me here ? I want to create a context based on package name.

Comment: Can you post booktype source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like one of the classes generated from your schema is called `Error`, and the compiler has picked the `java.lang.Error` class over the `com.store.web.ws.v1.model.Error` class.  Try putting an explicit

```
import com.store.web.ws.v1.model.Error;
```

at the top of `ObjectFactory.java` and recompiling it, or failing that edit the code to use fully-qualified class names.

```
public com.store.web.ws.v1.Error createError() {
  return new com.store.web.ws.v1.Error();
}
```

(or change the class name and remap it to the right element name using `@XmlRootElement(name="Error")`)

Comment: o wao. I copied those files from one workspace to other and editor made those changes. My createError was changed to `java.lang.Error createError()`. Changed it back to default `Error` object and it worked like a charm.